# SharePoint 2010 auditing policy for folder content type causes error

Tags: information-management, auditing

If I want to add an auditing policy on a folder content type I get an error

> the content type "Folder" at "/Shared Documents" is sealed.

Does this mean that it's impossible to add an information policy on a folder content type?

If yes why is this the case?

**UPDATE:**

Answer: [Unable to apply Folder Content Type Policy](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010general/thread/1aff3461-c697-4228-8d37-567b60ffd705)